# How do I change a parameter value before running the application

Tags: c#, openvpn

All I'm trying to do is to change the value of lport or increment it each time the loop ends with C#.

Here is my code:

```
Process.Start("D:\\OpenVPNPortable\\App\\bin\\openvpn.exe","--client --lport 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format` is the function to construct strings from values. Assuming some sort of port scanning `for` loop:

```
  for(var port = 80; port++; port <88)
  {
     Process.Start("D:\\OpenVPNPortable\\App\\bin\\openvpn.exe",
        String.Format("--client --lport {0}", port));
  }
```